# How to apply proxy and DNS settings to GNU/Linux Debian using configuration management tool such as Ansible

Tags: proxy, dns, debian, configuration-management, ansible

I'm new to configuration management tool.
I want to use Ansible.

I'd like to set proxy to several GNU/Linux Debian (in fact several Raspbian).

I'd like to append

```
export http_proxy=http://cache.domain.com:3128
```

to `/home/pi/.bashrc`

I also want to append

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://cache.domain.com:3128";
```

to `/etc/apt.conf`

I want to set DNS to IP `X1.X2.X3.X4` creating a
`/etc/resol.conf` file with

```
nameserver X1.X2.X3.X4
```

What playbook file should I write ? How should I apply this playbook to my servers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second jpmens. This is a very basic problem in Ansible, and a very good way to get started using the docs, tutorials and example playbooks.

However, if you're stuck or in a hurry, you can solve this like this (everything takes place on the "ansible master") :

Create a roles structure like this :

```
cd your_playbooks_directory
mkdir -p roles/pi/{templates,tasks,vars}
```

Now create roles/pi/tasks/main.yml :

```
- name: Adds resolv.conf
  template: src=resolv.conf.j2 dest=/etc/resolv.conf mode=0644

- name: Adds proxy env setting to pi user
  lineinfile: dest=~pi/.bashrc regexp="^export http_proxy" insertafter=EOF line="export http_proxy={{ http_proxy }}"
```

Then roles/pi/templates/resolv.conf.j2 :

```
nameserver {{ dns_server }}
```

then roles/pi/vars/main.yml :

```
dns_server: 8.8.8.8
http_proxy: http://cache.domain.com:3128
```

Now make a top-level playbook to apply roles, at your playbook root, and call it site.yml :

```
- hosts : raspberries
  roles:
    - { role: pi }
```

You can apply your playbook using :

```
ansible-playbook site.yml
```

assuming your machines are in the raspberries group.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Start by learning a bit about [Ansible basics](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/) and familiarize yourself with playbooks. Basically you ensure you can SSH in to your Raspian machines (using keys) and that the user Ansible invokes on these machines can run *sudo*. (That's the hard  bit.)

The easy bit is creating the playbook for the tasks at hand, and there are plenty of pointers to [example playbooks](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples) in the documentation.

If you really want to add a line to a file or two, use the `lineinfile` module, although I strongly recommend you create templates for the files you want to *push* to your machines and use those with the `template` module. (`lineinfile` can get quite messy.)

Comment: `lineinfile`.. ! Been using Ansible for a bit and hadn't noticed that. Templates are definitely better, but sometimes things like this are very helpful.